# SharedPreferences can pass but doesn't save

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

**I can pass** data with SharedPreferences to second activity from first activity. It works. However, When **I close and open** the project in the emulator, It **doesn't save** it.

(There are other codes in second activity but I don't want to confuse your mind. I think problem is not related to them because I don't get any error. Nevertheless, you want them, I can instantly share.)

First activity:

```
private float difference;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myMain);
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == button1.getId()){
            editor.putFloat("float1", difference);
            editor.commit();}
 if(v.getId() == set.getId()){
            editor.putFloat("float2", difference);
            editor.commit();}
 if(v.getId() == sleepB.getId()){
            editor.putFloat("float3", difference);
            editor.commit();}
}
```

Second activity:

```
Float intValue, intValue2, intValue3;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily);
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}

private Object[] createItem(long timestamp) {
       data = new ArrayList<>();
        s= getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
        if(s != null) {
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        try {
            date2 = formatter.parse(s);
            timeStampDate = new Timestamp((date2.getTime()));
            myTime = timeStampDate.getTime();
            editor.putLong("long1",myTime);
            editor.commit();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        otherMyTime = sharedPreferences.getLong("long1",0);
        intValue = sharedPreferences.getFloat("float1", (float) 0.0);
        intValue2 = sharedPreferences.getFloat("float2", (float)0.0);
        intValue3 = sharedPreferences.getFloat("float3",(float) 0.0);

        item = new Object[COLUMN_NAMES.length];
        item[0] = otherMyTime;
        item[1] = intValue;
        item[2] = intValue2;
        item[3] = intValue3;
        data.add(item);
    }

        item = new Object[COLUMN_NAMES.length];
        item[0] = timestamp;
        item[1] = 0;
        item[2] = 0;
        item[3] = 0;
        data.add(item);

        cursor.addAll(data);
    return item; }
```

Comment: Maybe you are using SharedPreferences elsewhere but you don't use those just to pass data between activities. You can use putExtra.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, float)

Comment: I was using Intent.putExtra but It doesn't save data. I need to save them. @KiarashTorkian

Comment: Are you actually triggering the onClick to save the preferences? Add logs and debug to find the problem to make sure the flow of events that you're expecting is happening. Don't just give up.

Comment: My guess is that you might be replacing the values when you restart your app. But it's hard to tell from the snippets. Might be better if you post both the activities.

Comment: @KiarashTorkian can be right because the second item object (I added check edit please) gives the current month each time. For instance, I see now 01/10/2017 to 31/10/2017. Firstly, I add all of them with sharedPrefences and there is no problem It passes and works. Secondly, When I open and close project, second item object works because of s==null, so not working otherMyTime. just working timestamp. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save float value in the shared preference you need to add like this.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putFloat("floatname", 1.5f);
editor.commit();
```

and then retrieve the float from shared preference is like this

```
float someFloat = prefs.getFloat("floatname", 0.0f);
```

add f at the end of the float value

Comment: what is the data type of intValue in the SecondActivity

Comment: float somevalue= prefs.getFloat("floatname", 0.0f);

this code is not working on your side?